# Choosing a minimum hash size for a given allowable number of collisions

Tags: hash, size, probability, collision

I am parsing a large amount of network trace data.  I want to split the trace into chunks, hash each chunk, and store a sequence of the resulting hashes rather than the original chunks.  The purpose of my work is to identify identical chunks of data - I'm hashing the original chunks to reduce the data set size for later analysis.  It is acceptable in my work that we trade off the possibility that collisions occasionally occur in order to reduce the hash size (e.g. 40 bit hash with 1% misidentification of identical chunks might beat 60 bit hash with 0.001% misidentification).

My question is, given a) number of chunks to be hashed and b) allowable percentage of misidentification, how can one go about choosing an appropriate hash size?

As an example:

1,000,000 chunks to be hashed, and we're prepared to have 1% misidentification (1% of hashed chunks appear identical when they are not identical in the original data).  How do we choose a hash with the minimal number of bits that satisifies this?

I have looked at materials regarding the [Birthday Paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_paradox), though this is concerned specifically with the probability of a *single* collision.  I have also looked at materials which discuss choosing a size based on an acceptable probability of a single collision, but have not been able to extrapolate from this how to choose a size based on an acceptable probability of *n* (or fewer) collisions.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the quality of your hash function matters, but some easy probability theory will probably help you here.

The question is what exactly are you willing to accept, is it good enough that you have an expected number of collisions at only 1% of the data? Or, do you demand that the probability of the number of collisions going over some bound be something?  If its the first, then back of the envelope style calculation will do:

Expected number of pairs that hash to the same thing out of your set is (1,000,000 C 2)*P(any two are a pair).  Lets assume that second number is 1/d where d is the the size of the hashtable.  (Note: expectations are linear, so I'm not cheating very much so far).  Now, you say you want 1% collisions, so that is 10000 total.  Well, you have (1,000,000 C 2)/d = 10,000, so d = (1,000,000 C 2)/10,000 which is according to google about 50,000,000.

So, you need a 50 million ish possible hash values. That is a less than 2^26, so you will get your desired performance with somewhere around 26 bits of hash (depending on quality of hashing algorithm).  I probably have a factor of 2 mistake in there somewhere, so you know, its rough.

If this is an offline task, you cant be *that* space constrained.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like a fun exercise!

Someone else might have a better answer, but I'd go the brute force route, provided that there's ample time:

Run the hashing calculation using incremental hash size and record the collision percentage for each hash size.

You might want to use binary search to reduce the search space.